# What is it called when a random variable is weakly greater than another for all elements of the sample space?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references, terminology, definition, stochastic-ordering

Suppose I have random variables $(X_1,X_2)$ defined on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ such that for any element $\omega \in \Omega$, $X_1(\omega) \geq X_2(\omega)$.

I'm looking to work with such a setting, and am having trouble finding any references or work on this. In particular, I hope to model the dependency between $(X_1,X_2)$, and also think about an outcome conditional on $X_1,X_2$. I am hoping to find some references that consider a similar problem or setting.  Is there a name for this kind of relationship? The best I could find was that of zeroth order stochastic dominance (or [statewise dominance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance#:%7E:text=Statewise%20dominance,-The%20simplest%20case&text=Random%20variable%20A%20is%20statewise,in%20at%20least%20one%20state.)), but there is almost no discussion on these settings, with most of the focus on first order stochastic dominance. Anyone have any thoughts or references?

I was thinking maybe there's a class of copulas that encode this information, but there isn't one to my knowledge (?) ...

Comment: You could ask about a copula encoding that information. There certainly is one (that is, many), but maybe not with a garden variety name ...

Comment: Ordinarily we would just say $X_1-X_2$ is a non-negative random variable.

Comment: What do you mean by 'weakly' greater?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen yes, that would be great, but I've had trouble finding any discussion of such a copula. Do you have any examples perchance ?

Comment: @whuber Yes that would certainly be fine, but I am interesting in modeling the dependence between $X_1$ and $X_2$, and perhaps even an outcome conditional on those two rvs, so not sure how helpful that would be for my setting. Tried to clarify a bit more in my question.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus weakly greater exactly as in my definition: $X_1(\omega) \geq X_2(\omega)$ for any $\omega \in \Omega$.

Comment: Why do you refer this type of inequality as *weakly* greater? Why is it a weak type of inequality? You mean to contrast $\geq$ with $>$ or something else?

Comment: It is unclear why Whuber's characterisation is not helpful. You have $X_1-X_2 \geq 0$ for every possible outcome $\omega$, so also conditional on $X_1$ or $X_2$ you will have  $X_1-X_2 \geq 0$.

Comment: BTW, a copula couldn't possibly encode this information: it is lost in the univariate marginal transformations.  *E.g.,* the copula for $(X_1,X_2)$ is identical to the copula for $(X_1-10^{100},X_2).$  Also, if you are modeling the dependence by regressing $X_1$ on $X_2$ (that is, you are studying the conditional expectation $E[X_1\mid X_2]$) then the relation $E[X_1-X_2\mid X_2] = E[X_1\mid X_2] - X_2$ makes it easy to convert between results for $(X_1-X_2,X_2)$ and results for $(X_1,X_2).$

Comment: @whuber re: copulas, I was thinking something along the lines of if $X_1 \leq X_2$, then if the post-normalized rvs are $(U_1,U_2)$, you would also have extra baggage that $U_1 \leq F_1 \circ F_2^{-1}(U_2)$, where $F_1,F_2$ are the cdfs of $X_1,X_2$.

Comment: I will take your advice and always carry the $X_1-X_2 \geq 0$ in my work. And yes, @SextusEmpiricus the term 'weakly' was for contrasting $\geq$ with $>$.

Comment: @whuber sorry if being slow, but could you flesh out what you mean by the copula not being able to encode the information? If I compare $(X_1,X_2)$ to $(Z,X_2)$ where $Z = X_1 - 10^{100}$, that $X_1 \leq X_2$ implies the copulas will not be the same?